# Snippets on google sheets

Tags: replace, google-sheets, code-snippets

I have to answer a F.A.Q by google sheets, and I have a list of models answers. I wanted a way to do a snippet in google sheets

for example if a type "@answer1" he replace for my model answer number 1.

Thanks

Comment: can you share a sample sheet - you can use regexreplace to do this or vlookup  - but need to see what we are working with

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a combination of an Index and Match function. You could use Vlookup also but I prefer Index Match as it is more flexible and performant.

If you type @answer 1 into any one of cells a1:a3 and then put your lookup table in cells c1:d3 then put the following formula into b1:

```
=index($D$1:$D$3,match(A1,$C$1:$C$3,0))
```

`cmd/ctrl + d` it down to fill the rest of the table.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWjjh.png